# Magento 1.9 creating a widget ends with adding layout update

Tags: magento-1.9, widget

I'm trying to create a **widget** via **admin panel**.

Created first a `static block`, via **widget** selected the right `theme/store` etc, but at the bottom to select `add layout update` it ends there. No reaction.

Is there something disabled? Do I have to turn something **on in the backend**?

Why is the `add layout update` button disabled?

[image]

Comment: add screenshot and more information

Comment: edit with screenshot, the button of layout update is not reacting

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: no errors for so far I know. browser is working normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem once; I think you can solve it by changing your admins language.

[image]

Comment: tnx! That's it.